# How can I use Linq and c# to compare a property against a List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have code that is filtering a List using code like this..

```
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>() { /*<INIT THE COLLECTION>*/ }
    //get the ones you need.
    var newListOfProducts = products.Where(p=>p.MyProperty == "prop1" || p.MyProperty == "prop2" || p.MyProperty == "prop3");
```

My preferences is to use syntax like this...

```
List<string> stringsToCompare = new List<string>() {"prop1","prop2","prop3"};
var newListOfProducts = products.Where(p=>p.MyProperty.IsInList(stringsToCompare));
```

This way I can dynamically build the stringToCompare instead of hard-coding them.

But I can't figure out how to do it despite googling for the last half-hour.  I think Intersect or Union can work but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: I've been trying for half an hour too, looks like it's impossible to get an Icomparer that will do it. I was trying for this: 
List<PropertyInfo> validProps = origProps.Intersect(newProps, new PropComparer((x, y) => x.Equals(y))).ToList();

Answer (score 5):

Flip it around and use `stringsToCompare.Contains`:

```
var newListOfProducts = products.Where(p => stringsToCompare.Contains(p.MyProperty));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just flip it around:

```
List<string> stringsToCompare = new List<string>() {"prop1","prop2","prop3"};
var newListOfProducts = products.Where(p=>stringsToCompare.Contains(p.MyProperty));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `HashSet` instead of a `List`

```
var stringsToCompare = new HashSet<string>() {"prop1","prop2","prop3"};
var newListOfProducts = products.Where(p => stringsToCompare.Contains(p.MyProperty));
```